# ServiceStack.Text doesn't install in Windows Phone 8 project through Nuget

Tags: windows-phone-8, servicestack, servicestack-text

Can't install ServiceStack.Text package using nuget in a Windows Phone 8 project. The message I get is

> Could not install package 'ServiceStack.Text 4.0.5'. You are trying to install this package > into a project that targets 'WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0', but the package does not contain
>   any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more 
>   information, contact the package author.

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Express 2012 for Windows Phone.
I also updated Nuget to the latest version, as it was a common solution I found for the same problem in other libraries.

Comment: The same for me. You can try download the code source from guthub: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text

Comment: Thanks d.lavysh, but I wanted to release the application as open source. Using nuget seems to be the only reasonable choice. Do you see it any other way?

Comment: Why you think that you can't use open-source git hub project in your project?

Comment: Same issue here for WP8.1 and StackService 4.0.22. I manually add a reference to ServiceStack.Client.PCL (using the winstore folder). It compile, but crash just after the first query.